# macOS, Dockerfile mounting a folder cannot change locale

Tags: django, macos, docker

I'm trying to mount a folder with my docker file instead of copying it on build. We use git for development and I don't want to rebuild the image everytime I make a change for testing.

my docker file is now as such

```
#set base image
FROM centos:centos7.2.1511

MAINTAINER Alex <alex@app.com>

#install yum dependencies
RUN yum -y update \\
&&  yum -y install yum-plugin-ovl \
&&  yum -y install epel-release \
&&  yum -y install net-tools \
&&  yum -y install gcc \
&&  yum -y install python-devel \
&&  yum -y install git \
&&  yum -y install python-pip \
&&  yum -y install openldap-devel \
&&  yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel \
&&  yum -y install libxslt-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel \
&&  yum -y install libevent-devel \
&&  yum -y install openldap-devel \
&&  yum -y install net-snmp-devel \
&&  yum -y install mysql-devel \
&&  yum -y install python-dateutil \
&&  yum -y install python-pip \
&&  pip install --upgrade pip

# Create the DIR
#RUN mkdir -p /var/www/itapp

# Set the working directory 
#WORKDIR /var/www/itapp

# Copy the app directory contents into the container 
#ADD . /var/www/itapp

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
#RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Make port available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8000

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME itapp

# Run server when the container launches
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

ive commented out the creation and copy of the itapp Django files as I want to mount them instead, (do I need to rebuild this first?)

then my command for mounting is

```
docker run -it -v /Users/alex/itapp:/var/www/itapp itapp bash
```

I now get an error:

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_COLLATE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_MESSAGES: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_NUMERIC: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_TIME: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

and the dev instance does not run.

how would I also set the working directory to the the volume that I'm mounting at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command. `-w WORKDIR` option in `docker run` sets working directory inside the container.

`docker run -d -v /Users/alex/itapp:/var/www/itapp -w /var/www/itapp itapp`

Also, you'll to map your container port to your host port to be able to access, for example, from a browser to your app.

To do this, use the following command.

`docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -v /Users/alex/itapp:/var/www/itapp -w /var/www/itapp itapp`

After this, your app should be running in `localhost:8000`

Comment: that did the trick, had to tinker with my docker file by ucommenting the mkdir and requirements files, and working dir, but it works perfectly! thanks!